# How to make an animation with a class which doesn't have a dependency property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d-model

As we know, we usually use **DoubleAnimation** or **StoryBoard** to make an animation in WPF, and dependency property normally get involved in this work. And my goal is to make an explosion animation.

I'm using **SciChart** to import some waterfront obj parts to my WPF project, it has a class named **ObjectModel3D** which is great to place the parts to locations that I want, **ObjectModel3D** has a dependency property named **Position** which is a **Vector3D** type, and **Position.X(Y,Z)** is a float non-dependency-property.

Here is some documentation for **ObjectModel3D**: [SciChart-ObjectModel3D](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/webframe.html#SciChart.Charting3D%7ESciChart.Charting3D.Visuals.Object.ObjectModel3D_members.html)

Here is my XAML code:

```
<s3D:SciChart3DSurface.SceneObjects>
            
            <object:ObjectModel3D TextureSource="{StaticResource WhiteTexture}"
                                  Source="{StaticResource Chassis}" Position="50,50,-50"
                                  CoordinateMode="WorldCoordinates"
                                  Scale="0.1,0.1,0.1"
                                  x:Name="ChassisModel"
                                  Rotation="{StaticResource Rotation3DX}"></object:ObjectModel3D>
            <object:ObjectModel3D TextureSource="{StaticResource WhiteTexture}"
                                  Source="{StaticResource Shell}" Position="-25,50,-50"
                                  CoordinateMode="WorldCoordinates"
                                  Scale="0.1,0.1,0.1"
                                  Rotation="{StaticResource Rotation3DY}"
                                  x:Name="ShellModel"></object:ObjectModel3D>
            <object:ObjectModel3D TextureSource="{StaticResource WhiteTexture}"
                                  Source="{StaticResource SpinModule}" Position="47,68,-35"
                                  CoordinateMode="WorldCoordinates"
                                  Scale="0.1,0.1,0.1"
                                  Rotation="{StaticResource Rotation3DX}"
                                  x:Name="SpinModuleModel"></object:ObjectModel3D>
            <object:ObjectModel3D TextureSource="{StaticResource WhiteTexture}"
                                  Source="{StaticResource Motor}" Position="40,50,-20"
                                  CoordinateMode="WorldCoordinates" 
                                  Scale="0.1,0.1,0.1"
                                  x:Name="MotorModel"></object:ObjectModel3D>
        </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.SceneObjects>
```

Here is a pic :
[image]

code that I tried with **DoubleAnimation**:

```
_3dObject obj3d = new _3dObject();
        var animationChassis = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = obj3d.ChassisModel.Position.X,
            To = 100,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        };
        obj3d.ChassisModel.BeginAnimation(ObjectModel3D.PositionProperty,animationChassis);
```

**ObjectModel3D** doesn't have a dependency property similar to "OffSetXProperty" like **TranslateTransform3D** does, so this code doesn't work.

Code that I tried with **StoryBoard**:

```
_3dObject obj3d = new _3dObject();
Vector3 vector3 = new Vector3();
vector3.X = obj3d.ChassisModel.Position.X;

var animationChassis = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = obj3d.ChassisModel.Position.X,
            To = 100,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        };

Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
Storyboard.SetTarget(animationChassis,obj3d.ChassisModel);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationChassis,new PropertyPath("(ObjectModel3D.PositionProperty)"));
// Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationChassis,new PropertyPath("(Position)"));
storyboard.Children.Add(animationChassis);
storyboard.Begin();
```

This is same reason, **StoryBoard** doesn't have a specific axis, so it can't work either.

My solution is :

```
private void WaterWaveButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread( new ThreadStart(Move));
    t.Start();
}

private void Move()
{
    Vector3 curVector3 = new Vector3(50, 50, -50);
    modelComplete.ChassisModel.Position = curVector3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        modelComplete.ChassisModel.Position.X += 1;
        Thread.Sleep(20);
    }
}
```

It worked, but little smoothly.

I'd like to know if you have any other ideas to make this animation work, please.

Thanks!!

Update 1:

Thanks @o_w for your advise, This is the first idea appeared to me, here is added dependency property code:

```
 public class OffSetProperty : ObjectModel3D
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ZProperty;

    static OffSetProperty()
    {
        XProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("X",typeof(float),typeof(OffSetProperty), 
            new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnXChangedCallBack)));
        
        YProperty= DependencyProperty.Register("Y", typeof(float), typeof(OffSetProperty),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnYChangedCallBack));

        ZProperty  =DependencyProperty.Register("Z", typeof(float), typeof(OffSetProperty), 
            new PropertyMetadata(OnZChangedCallBack));
    }

    public float X
    {
        get { return (float) GetValue(XProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XProperty,value);}
    }

    public float Y
    {
        get { return (float) GetValue(YProperty); }
        set { SetValue(YProperty,value);}
    }

    public float Z
    {
        get { return (float) GetValue(ZProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ZProperty,value);}
    }

    private static void OnXChangedCallBack(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OffSetProperty property = sender as OffSetProperty;

        if (property != null)
        {
            property.Position.X = property.X;
        }
    }

    private static void OnYChangedCallBack(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OffSetProperty property = sender as OffSetProperty;
        if (property !=null)
        {
            property.Position.Y= property.Y ;
        }
    }

    private static void OnZChangedCallBack(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OffSetProperty property = sender as OffSetProperty;
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.Position.Z =  property.Z ;
        }
    }
}
```

Button_Click code:

```
_3dObject obj3d = new _3dObject();
        var animationChassis = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = obj3d.ChassisModel.Position.X,
            To = 100f,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        };
        obj3d.ChassisModel.BeginAnimation(OffSetProperty.XProperty,animationChassis);


XAML code:

<local:OffSetProperty TextureSource="{StaticResource WhiteTexture}"
                                  Source="{StaticResource Chassis}" 
                                  Position="50,50,-50"
                                  X="50" Y="50" Z="-50"
                                  CoordinateMode="WorldCoordinates"
                                  Scale="0.1,0.1,0.1"
                                  Rotation="{StaticResource Rotation3DX}"
                                  x:Name="ChassisModel"></local:OffSetProperty>
            <local:OffSetProperty TextureSource="{StaticResource WhiteTexture}"
                                  Source="{StaticResource Shell}"
                                  Position="-25,50,-50"
                                  X="-25" Y="50" Z="-50"
                                  CoordinateMode="WorldCoordinates"
                                  Scale="0.1,0.1,0.1"
                                  Rotation="{StaticResource Rotation3DY}"
                                  x:Name="ShellModel"></local:OffSetProperty>
            <local:OffSetProperty TextureSource="{StaticResource WhiteTexture}"
                                  Source="{StaticResource SpinModule}"
                                  Position="47,68,-35"
                                  X="47" Y="68" Z="-35"
                                  CoordinateMode="WorldCoordinates"
                                  Scale="0.1,0.1,0.1"
                                  Rotation="{StaticResource Rotation3DX}"
                                  x:Name="SpinModuleModel"></local:OffSetProperty>
            <local:OffSetProperty TextureSource="{StaticResource WhiteTexture}"
                                  Source="{StaticResource Motor}"
                                  Position="40,50,-20"
                                  X="40" Y="50" Z="-20"
                                  CoordinateMode="WorldCoordinates"
                                  Scale="0.1,0.1,0.1"
                                  x:Name="MotorModel"></local:OffSetProperty>
```

but I got an error :

ArgumentException: Type“System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation” in AnimationTimeline cannot apply to running dynamic type“System.Single” “X”property。
ArgumentName: animation

I didn't figure out how I got this error..

Comment: ObjectModel3D inherits from FrameworkElement and does have Dependency Properties, just not Position property. Did you try to wrap it in another class with MyPosition DependencyProperty, that can be animated, and add to it an OnMyPositionPropertyChanged method to modify Position property with the new incoming value?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but did work, I updated my tried code, I will be appreciated if you could give me an advise.

Comment: Did you leave the DoubleAnimation? As the name suggests it works with changes to type of Double, so if your property is of type Float it will not work. You could make your new DependencyProperties of type Double, so the animation will work(that was my intention), and so any change to X property will get you into OnXPropertyChanged, cast to float, and set the value for the existing Position property.